# How to create an object reference variable based on a variable

Tags: java, variables

This is kind of complicated, but I need to have my program to be able to detect, which class to reference based on the data of an array.

I know how to do this by using a huge if statement, but that would be a HUGE amount of code. Is there a way to like put the variable so that it would be like
 
`String x; x new = new x();`
 if you get the idea. `x` would hold the class name. Or is there another way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use reflection. It's not exactly fixed the way you are describing though...

Comment: This feels like an XY problem/question .. can you explain the task better? This desired approach *cannot* work in a static-typed manner as envisioned. The "best" that could be done based on a stricter interpretation of the question is: `Object x = CreateInstanceOfSomeTypeDynamically(str)` or similar. Note that this results in 1) a fixed variable name (`x`) and 2) not a very useful type refinement on said variable (an interface of supertype could unify a bit, but it feels like an XY problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Java Reflection for this.  Here's a [link to the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).  [This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) will be the most relevant.  Here's an example of what you can do:

```
String x = ...
Class c = Class.forName(x);
X x = c.newInstance()
```